# Javascript formatting exception

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I am using inner join on three tables and i am displaying the resulting table . I am using the Xml for this .

```
<SQLInformation>
      <Table>tblechecklistprogramworkpackagexref prwpxref</Table>
      <TableJoins>
        INNER JOIN tblechecklistprogram pr ON pr.ixProgram=prwpxref.ixProgram
        INNER JOIN tblechecklistworkpackage wp ON wp.ixWorkPackage=prwpxref.ixWorkPackage
        INNER JOIN tblechecklistworkpackageactivityxref wpaxref ON wpaxref.ixWorkPackage=wp.ixWorkPackage
        INNER JOIN tblechecklistactivity act ON act.ixActivity=wpaxref.ixActivity
      </TableJoins>
      <WhereClause>
      </WhereClause>
      <GroupBy>
      </GroupBy>
      <OrderBy></OrderBy>
      <HeaderInformation></HeaderInformation>
      <FooterInformation></FooterInformation>
    </SQLInformation>
    <Columns>
      <Column>
        <Id>ProgramName</Id>
        <Title>Program Name</Title>
        <Table>pr</Table>
        <Field>sName</Field>
        <Alias>sName</Alias>
        <Sortable>true</Sortable>
        <GroupSort>true</GroupSort>
        <ColumnWidth>100</ColumnWidth>
        <JavascriptFormatter>
          <![CDATA[
            DesignDataFileFormatter = function(span,row,columns,data,item)
            {              
              $(span).createAppend('a', {href: '../EcheckList/TemplateUsage.aspx?IxTemplate=' + 2, title: 'Go to Corresponding Schedule Item.', innerHTML:sName });

              return true;
            }
          ]]>
        </JavascriptFormatter>
        <Display>true</Display>
        <Filter type="Database">
          <FilterContainer name="Program" DisplayMember="sName" ValueMember="ixProgram" UseHavingClause="false" >
            <FilterQuery>SELECT sName,ixProgram FROM tblechecklistprogram</FilterQuery>
          </FilterContainer>
        </Filter>
      </Column>
```

I want to create a hyperlink using one of the column values of the output table. Whenever I click on the link it is giving format exception.

Comment: Now iam able to redirect to the page .. But if i want to pass values to the page,how can i do it ? And I want clearance about what value should be given in href .. Why its giving an error for the virtual path ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution the problem was with the virtual path ..

$(span).createAppend('a', { href : 'Customer.aspx?ixProgram=' + row[columns.ixProgram] }).text(data);
                  return true;
                }
              ]]>